# Correctly getting all digits of very long integer in R

Tags: python, r

**[Problem Here.](https://projecteuler.net/problem=16)**

I tried solving the problem 16 of Project Euler using R, but the result I get is not what I'm able to get with other programming languages. Apparently the answer obtained by solving using R is wrong. Can anyone point out what's wrongly happening in R?

In R:

```
digits <- sprintf("%f", 2^1000)
digits <- strsplit(digits, ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
digits <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(digits, "")))
sum(digits)
>1200
```

In python:

```
sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))
>1366
```

On checking, I found that `sprintf("%f", 2^1000)` in R and `str(2**1000)` in Python produce different outputs. Please explain.

**Edit:**

Including my system details:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "2.0"

$year
[1] "2015"

$month
[1] "04"

$day
[1] "16"

$`svn rev`
[1] "68180"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)"

$nickname
[1] "Full of Ingredients"
```

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine, but on mine (Ubuntu 15.04) and using R version 3.2.2, I get a sum of 1366.

Comment: I checked in 3.2.0 and 3.2.1, but I'm getting 1200 as the answer. Using windows 8. Do you think its because of OS or R.Version?

Comment: Just tried with R version 2.15.3 and I still get 1366.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, I too just tried in a RHEL machine and got 1366. I guess its the problem with OS itself. I got 1200 in two of the windows machines.

Comment: This is interesting. But I cannot explain why, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `2^1000` is larger than what can be stored in a 32-bit signed integer (`.Machine$integer.max` is 2147483647). So it's converted to a double precision float, which only has ~15-17 significant digits of precision (the rest is rounding).

You need to use a class designed to handle 64-bit integers if you want to do this calculation exactly.

```
require(gmp)
digits <- sprintf("%f", as.bigz(2)^1000)
digits <- strsplit(digits, ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
digits <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(digits, "")))
sum(digits)
# [1] 1366
```

Comment: I'm still getting 1200 using your code. Can you provide details of your OS? I feel this problem is only occurring in Windows.

Comment: I'm using 64-bit R installed on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Have run this code on 3 Windows 64-bit machines and 2 RHEL x64 machines. All windows machines gave output of 1200 in R (1366 in Python) and both of the RHEL machines gave 1366 in R as well as Python. So I'm concluding that Windows is the culprit for now. Still would be better if there is a concrete explanation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference between R an Python:

In Python the interpreter detects that 2^1000 is an integer, and an integer too large to be representable by a machine word. So it automatically switches to specialized large integer calculations, which give you the exact result.

In R on the other hand, 2^1000 is simply calculated as a floating point value, so we cannot - in general - expect perfectly accurate results.

The fact that on some machines using R 2^1000 returns the *right* result is actually surprising and a lucky coincidence! It is probably related to the fact that 2^1000 happens to be exactly representable as a double precision floating point number. So, if 2^1000 gets calculated via actual multiplications the result will be incorrect. But if "the computer" realizes that 2^1000 is a special number when using binary representations, it can skip these calculations and directly set the correct floating point bit pattern, resulting in an exact value. Just maybe this explains why you sometimes get the correct result and sometimes not...?

Anyway, for reproducible results, explicitly use a "big int" library like `gmp` in R too:

```
> library(gmp)
> sum(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(as.character(as.bigz(2) ^ 1000), ""))))
[1] 1366
```

Comment: tried `gmp` and `bit64`, but they are of no help in my Windows machine. The result is still 1200.

Comment: What version of gmp are you using on these machines? You can check with gmpVersion() in R. On my machine, which produces the correct result, it is 5.0.2.

Comment: my gmp version is 6.0.0